# SetTimeout mutates my state despite I am using prevState

Tags: reactjs, search, settimeout, immutability

SetTimeout mutates my state despite I am using prevState. The first search function works and filters out the array. setData filters and changes the data array completely. If you type something, search and delete input, you can't see the data back.

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();

  // sets inputValue state for each keystroke
  const inputValueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    // creates timer for filtering data
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setData((prevState) => {
        // sets filter object after one second in order to filter results
        const filteredData = prevState
          // filters data according to filter value
          .filter((item, index) => {
            // return array of object values and drill down the array
            const flattenedItem = Object.values(item).map((itemLevel2) => {
              // if typeof the itemLevel2 is object (address, company), convert it to array else return the string
              if (typeof itemLevel2 === "object") {
                return Object.values(itemLevel2).map((itemLevel3) => {
                  // if typeof the itemLevel3 is object (geo), convert it to an array else return the string
                  if (typeof itemLevel3 === "object") {
                    return Object.values(itemLevel3);
                  } else {
                    return itemLevel3;
                  }
                });
              } else {
                return itemLevel2;
              }
            });

            return flattenedItem
              .flat(2) // creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth (2).
              .join(" ") // converts array to string
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()); // searches if string includes filterValue
          });
        return filteredData;
      });

      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000);

    // clear timer while unmounting
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <StyledApp>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Card key={item.id}>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </StyledApp>
  );
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/search-component-z33wc

Comment: The issue is not `mutating` the issue is that once you filtered and set `data` to the filtered value you don't have the other objects in the `data` anymore so when you remove the filter there is no way they can come back, the solution is to save the original data in a separate piece of state and use the original data every time you need to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another state and storing data in it and filtering it solved the problem.

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();

  
  // sets inputValue state for each keystroke
  const inputValueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    // creates timer for filtering data
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setFilteredData((prevState) => {
        // sets filter object after one second in order to filter results
        const filteredData = [...data]
          // filters data according to filter value
          .filter((item, index) => {
            // return array of object values and drill down the array
            const flattenedItem = Object.values(item).map((itemLevel2) => {
              // if typeof the itemLevel2 is object (address, company), convert it to array else return the string
              if (typeof itemLevel2 === "object") {
                return Object.values(itemLevel2).map((itemLevel3) => {
                  // if typeof the itemLevel3 is object (geo), convert it to an array else return the string
                  if (typeof itemLevel3 === "object") {
                    return Object.values(itemLevel3);
                  } else {
                    return itemLevel3;
                  }
                });
              } else {
                return itemLevel2;
              }
            });

            return flattenedItem
              .flat(2) // creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth (2).
              .join(" ") // converts array to string
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()); // searches if string includes filterValue
          });
        return filteredData;
      });

      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000);

    // clear timer while unmounting
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [inputValue, data]);

  return (
    <>
      {filteredData.map((item) => (
        <Card key={item.id}>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```